# otimizar datatable jquery com um banco com mais de 30.000 registros

Tags: javascript, json

qual a melhor maneira de otimizar o retorno de dados do banco?
o ideal seria armazenar (no server-side) todos os dados (select * from dados) em uma array de objetos e mandar para o client-side? a partir daí eu faço o tratamento dessa array via javascript e vou populando na minha tabela?

fazer algo desse tipo? segue o link do jsfiddle abaixo
http://jsfiddle.net/V2Kdz/

algumas dicas?

Comment: Já pensou em usar `LIMIT ?, ?` e paginação? Sua questão é mais para SQL do que javascript propriamente dito ou estou enganado?

Comment: eu tenho um registro com 30k+ linhas, no php eu simplesmente dei um select * from dados e mandei printar no html, lá no html eu tenho um datatable que organiza todos esses dados. o problema é que está demorando um bom tempo pra carregar tudo. a ideia é printar todos os dados para que a pessoa possa consultar qualquer coisa via client-side.

Comment: Sim, mas ninguém carrega todos dados de uma vez, é totalmente inviável, por isto existe paginação e por isto sugeri o `LIMIT`.

Comment: Cara fiz um com 10k já dava problema. Tente trazer menos dados na query. O navegador trava com esse tanto de dado.

Comment: @João notei que todas suas perguntas anteriores tem respostas, mas você não aceitou nenhuma, se alguma daquelas respostas lhe resolveu os seus outros problemas marque-a como correta, se não sabe como fazer isto faça um tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Carregar todos dados de uma vez é uma péssima ideia, independente de você deixar eles guardados no front-end ou back-end, sempre limite os seus resultados, no caso de "banco de dados" a melhor solução é usar `LIMIT` (acredito que no SQL Server usemos `OFFSET` ao invés de `LIMIT`), assim você só deverá enviar ao front-end os dados da página solicitada.

Não sei qual banco você está usando, mas a sintaxe é bem semelhante na maioria dos bancos, funciona assim:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT [offset,] row_count
```

O `offset` é a posição no banco, o `row_count` é o limite de resultados que você irá exibir, note que se você usar assim:

```
SELECT ... LIMIT 10
```

Ele irá fazer o `offset` ser igual a `1` pois ele foi omitido e o 10 será o `row_count`.

Geralmente para cada paginação usamos um limite de 15 á 30 (isto vária conforme cada um).

No seu código há um `<select>` na opção `sLengthMenu` do `$.dataTable`, ele deve enviar o valor selecionado para o back-end, no caso se selecionou para mostrar 10, ele deve enviar uma requisição para o servidor e deve executar a query assim (`http://localhost/page.php?limit=10`):

> *Nota:* Eu não sei se você está usando mysql ou outro tipo de banco, mas a lógica é a mesma

```
$offset = 1;
$row_count = $_GET['limit'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ... LIMIT ?, ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $offset);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $row_count);

//query: SELECT ... LIMIT 1, 10;
```

Se você quiser ir para a página 2, deverá multiplicar o `$offset`, pela quantidade de linhas que irá exibir (`http://localhost/page.php/?page=2&limit=10`):

```
$offset = 1;

if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] > 1) {
    $offset = ($_GET['page'] - 1) * $_GET['limit'];
}

$row_count = $_GET['limit'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT ... LIMIT ?, ?');

$stmt->bind_param('i', $offset);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $row_count);

//query: SELECT ... LIMIT 10, 10;
```

- Página 3 (`http://localhost/page.php.php?page=3&limit=10`) irá gerar:

  ```
  SELECT ... LIMIT 20, 10;
  ```
- Página 4 (`http://localhost/page.php.php?page=4&limit=10`) irá gerar:

  ```
  SELECT ... LIMIT 30, 10;
  ```
- Página 5 (`http://localhost/page.php.php?page=5&limit=10`) irá gerar:

  ```
  SELECT ... LIMIT 40, 10;
  ```

Para usar com `WHERE`, faça algo como:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE foo='abc' OR foo='xyz' LIMIT 1, 10
```

E assim por diante.

### Documentação

- **MySql:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html
- **Sql Server 2008+**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms186734.aspx
- **Sql Server 2012 (compact):** https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx
- **PostgreSQL:** http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html
- **Oracle:** http://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1.php

Comment: lembrando que o OFFSET e o FETCH são recursos novos, apesar de muito uteis, só estão disponíveis no SqlServer 2012. para versões antigas tem que contornar este problema usando ROW_NUMBER()

Comment: @TobyMosque Obrigado, editado.

Comment: no campo busca (um input text), ele pesquisa toda a tabela ao digitar uma string (retorna do banco todas as palavras que contenham aquela string digitada), se eu fazer com limit, a busca não vai estar limitado somente nesse limit que fiz?

Comment: @João Você quer saber a quantidade de palavras encontradas?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o sistema de busca funciona igual aquele jsfiddle postado, não é necessário imprimir todo o banco de dados pra aquela função de busca funcionar? pelo que entendi, é impresso todos os dados no banco na tabela, daí o plugin de datatable do jquery só faz uma busca sem acessar o banco de dados, só pela tabela impressa. essa implementação não é uma boa ideia pra tabelas bem grandes, não é?

Comment: @João eu não acho pois vai demorar do back-end trazer todos os dados, mesmo que vc só traga a primeira vez.

Comment: seria melhor implementar isso que você falou (dos limits) e fazer uma busca mais otimizada, por exemplo: se eu quiser só procurar o nome, eu passo o nome e capturo no back-end, e mando um select * from nometabela WHERE nome='$nomeprocurada'; não é? sou meio novato nisso, rs. eu tenho uma tabela gigante e estou estudando formas pra implementa-la.

Comment: Isso @João ficaria algo como: `select * from nometabela WHERE nome='$nomeprocurada' LIMIT 1, 10;`

Answer (score 1):

Na opção `data` do ajax, passe uma função:

```
"data": function ( d ) {
    d.suavariavel = "seu valor";
}
```

Assim, você pode, através das variáveis, fazer um *select* limitando o número de registros retornados.
Segue um exemplo que utilizo e funciona perfeitamente:

```
var dtini  = $('#dtini').val();
var dtfim  = $('#dtfim').val();
var temp = $('#dtini').val().split("/");
var d1     = new Date(temp[2], temp[1]-1,temp[0]);
var temp = $('#dtfim').val().split("/");
var d2     = new Date(temp[2], temp[1]-1,temp[0]);
if (d2 < d1){
    errorAlert("Data final não pode ser maior que data inicial");
}else{
    var totcli = $('#totcli').dataTable({
        "bDeferRender"   : true,
        "bProcessing"    : true,
        "aaSorting"      : [],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "ajax"           : {
            "url" : "../php/rotinas.php",
            "type": "POST",
            "data": function (a) {
                a.vendaspr = 0;
                a.dtini    = dtini;
                a.dtfim    = dtfim;             
            }   
         }
    }); 
}
```

Nesse exemplo, retorno os registros que data entre a data inicial e final.

Answer (score 0):

Use o filtro `limit` no SQL e a técnica de paginação no lado do cliente, não precisa mandar uma enxurrada de dados de uma vez.